# How to search XML tree nodes to get parent of each node with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Lets say I have an XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:object xmlns:t="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/types-3"
   xmlns="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
   xmlns:c="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
                      xmlns:apti="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/api-types-3">    
          
               <apti:object oid="2">      
                  <name>34567892</name>
                  <parentOrgRef oid="1"/>      
               </apti:object>
            
               <apti:object oid="4">  
                  <name>50001007</name>
                  <parentOrgRef oid="3"/>
               </apti:object>
            
               <apti:object oid="5">    
                  <name>50001012</name>
                  <parentOrgRef oid="4"/>      
               </apti:object>
            
               <apti:object oid="6">      
                  <name>50001806</name>
                  <parentOrgRef oid="5"/>
               </apti:object>
            
               <apti:object oid="3">      
                  <name>50001802</name>
                  <parentOrgRef oid="2"/>      
               </apti:object>
                  
               <apti:object oid="7">  
                  <name>50001742</name>
                  <parentOrgRef oid="6"/>
               </apti:object>
            
               <apti:object oid="1">      
                <name>50001282</name>
                  <parentOrgRef oid="0"/>      
               </apti:object>
            </t:object>
```

I want to extract with XSLT the name of the parent-node for each node based on the oid.

for example

```
 <node>
    <name>34567892</name>
    <parent>50001282</parent>
  </node>
```

My XSLT is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
        xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
        xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
        xmlns:t="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/types-3"
        xmlns="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
        xmlns:c="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
         xmlns:apti="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/api-types-3"
        version="3.0">
    
      <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>    
      <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>    
    <xsl:key name="oid" match="apti:object" use="@oid"/>    
    <xsl:template match="apti:object[key('oid', @oid, /t:object)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), key('oid', @oid, /t:object)!(name)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/t:object/apti:object">
    <node>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="c:name"/></name>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('oid', @oid, /t:object)!(name)"/>
    </node>
    </xsl:template>       
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I can't get the name of the parent node with a template.
I have tried to search all the nodes with a condition for oid but it doesnt seem to work.

Please help

Comment: Please post a complete XSLT, not snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of output you show can be easily produced using:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
xmlns:t="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/types-3"
xmlns:apti="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/api-types-3"
exclude-result-prefixes="t apti">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="parent" match="apti:object" use="@oid" />

<xsl:template match="/t:object">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="apti:object">
            <node>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                </name>
                <parent>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('parent', parentOrgRef/ @oid)/name"/>
                </parent>
            </node>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvi4

---

Note that your XML contains a default namespace declaration that puts all the unprefixed elements in a namespace.